# How to define an async f# interface that can be implemented in c#?

Tags: c#, f#

I have defined an interface in F#

```ml
type IConnect =
    abstract Update: seq<DataType> -> Async<bool>
```

I would like other apps in the same appdomain to implement it so that I can call Update on any that implement the interface (I gather the implementations in an TinyIoC container). The return type `Async<bool>` can indicate if the update succeeded or not without having to wait for it. And I can update the apps in parallel.

The other apps are written in c# and when I started to write a reference (mock) implementation I realised that this would require any implementer to use a `FSharpAsync` type which is not very pretty.

So, how do I define the interface so that it is easy to implement in c# and keep the async aspects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) or perhaps [IObservable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx). You can convert between `async` workflows and `Task<T>` [quite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee837067.aspx) [easily](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee821132.aspx) and it is a simple type to work with in C# or most .Net languages.

```ml
type IConnect = abstract Update: seq<DataType> -> Task<bool>
```

Comment: Thank you, `Async.AwaitTask: Task<'a> -> Async<'a>` seems to work fine